# Como montar mosaico de 3 'colunas' CSS?

Tags: html, css, img

Estou tendo dificuldades para montar o mosaico do exemplo abaixo para a versão mobile do meu site

A versão em `orientation:portrait` deve ser algo similar a essa:

```
..........................
.          |             .
.  Img 1   |             .
.          |             .
...........|  Img 3      .
.          |             .
.          |             .
.  Img 2   |             .
..........................
```

E quando o site for colocado em `landscape`

Quero que as mesmas fiquem em 3 colunas assim:

```
  ...........................
  .      |        |         .
  .      |        |         .
  . Img1 | Img 2  | Img 3   .
  .      |        |         .      
  ...........................
```

Sobre as imagens qual o tamanho as mesmas devem ser?

Comment: Tem que ser CSS puro?

Comment: Aberto a todas as soluções, preferência css puro, mas se tiver outra solução boa eu aceito também.

Comment: Eu recomendo muito utilizar o Bootstrap, ele vai manter um responsivo limpo e as dimensões das imagens "não irão perder" seus pixels.

Answer (score 1):

Fiz inline para facilitar.

**Portrait:**

```
<div class="container1" style="width:50%;height:100px; float:left;">
  <img src="img1" style="heigth:50%;width:100%;">
  <img src="img2" style="heigth:50%;width:100%;">
</div>
<div class="container2" style="width:50%;">
  <img src="img3" style="heigth:100%;width:100%;">
</div>
```

**Landscape:**

```
<div class="container1" style="width:77%; height: 100px; float:left;">
  <img src="img1" style="heigth:100%;width:50%;">
  <img src="img2" style="heigth:100%;width:50%;">
</div>
<div class="container2" style="width:33%;">
  <img src="img3" style="heigth:100%;width:100%;">
</div>
```

**Media Querie você resolve**

Answer (score 0):

Pode separar "estas diferenças" em arquivos .CSS diferentes:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(orientation: portrait)" href="portrait.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(orientation: landscape)" href="landscape.css">
```

Ou ter um arquivo padrão que se aplica a tudo no seu site, e ter uma condição específica como p pseudo-código demonstra abaixo:

```
<style>
  @media (min-width: 500px) and (max-width: 600px) {
    .oqueseraalterado {
        width: 100px;
    }
  }
</style>
```

- [Veja aqui mais exemplos de media-queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/CSS_Media_queries)
- [Mais exemplos de uso](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ui/responsive/?hl=pt-br)

Answer (score 0):

Uma forma é usar o flex, junto às media-queries:

```css
.container{ 
  display: flex; 
  max-width: 300px; /* Você pode trocar a largura aqui livremente */
}

.container .all, .container .last{
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}

.all, .last{ width: 100%; }

.all .image, .last .image{
  width: 100%;
}

.last .image{
  width: 200%;
}


@media(orientation: landscape){
  .container{ 
    display: block;
    max-width: initial;
  }

  .container .all, .container .last{ 
    display: inline-block; 
    width: initial;
  }

  .image{
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto !important;
    height: 300px;
  }
  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="all">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" class="image" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" class="image" />
  </div>
  <div class="last">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/600x600" class="image" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente usar este CSS, uso em vários projetos e funciona perfeitamente pra mim.
Dá para personalizar com o número de colunas desejado.

```
#photos {
    line-height: 0;
   -webkit-column-count: 3;
   -webkit-column-gap:   0px;
   -moz-column-count:    3;
   -moz-column-gap:      0px;
   column-count:         3;
   column-gap:           0px;  
}

#photos img {
   width: 100% !important;
   height: auto !important;
}
```